# Авторизация пользователей NTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, авторизация, ldap, ntlm

Разрабатываю способ авторизации на сайте для небольшого проекта на Python и Flak и возник вопрос авторизации пользователей. Поскольку в сети имеется контролер домена, но решил использовать LDAP. После долго поиска в сети я так и не нашел ни какого способа сверить пароль введенный пользователем с тек, который сохранен в учетной записи AD. После прочтения нескольких статей я понял что этот протокол применяется для доступа к службе каталогов предприятия, а для авторизации пользователей нужно использовать NTLM или Kerberos, но что то у меня так и не получилось найти ни одной подходящей статьи. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аутентификацию с AD можно реализовать разными путями.

**1. Аутентификация по логину-паролю**

Если предполагается заставлять вводить логин-пароль пользователя в формочке на сайте, то тут достаточно стандартных LDAP функций от стандартного LDAP-модуля.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ldap

ldap_server = '192.169.0.100'
user = "vasya" + "@YOUR-DOMAIN.LOC"
password = "Sup3rVasy@"
connect = ldap.open(ldap_server)

try:
  connect.bind_s(user, password)
  print('Success')
except ldap.LDAPError:
  print('Invalid credentials')
```

Где "@YOUR-DOMAIN.LOC" - это имя (realm) вашего AD.

**2. NTLM/Kerberos**

Этот тип аутентификации обычно (но не обязательно) используют для "прозрачного" входа на сайт. Предполагается, что ПК юзера заджойнен в домен. Юзер с этого ПК открывает некий интранет-сайт. И попадает на/в него уже авторизованным на основе своих доменных реквизитов. Т.е. логин-пароль вводить не надо.

Данный тип аутентификации осуществляет веб-сервер после предварительных настроек.

Примеры конфигураций:

[Apache + NTLM](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/)

[Apache + Kerberos](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_apache_to_use_kerberos_authentication.html)

[Apache + Kerberos + PHP](https://robert.stadsbygd.net/2015/01/14/kerberos-auth-with-apachephp/)

В этом типе аутентификации веб-сервер определяет "валидность" юзера, инициализируя переменную `REMOTE_USER`, которую в последствии можно обработать в движке сайта.